# Why can DialogFlow's fullfillment_text and fulfillment_message differ?

Tags: dialogflow-es

when I say "Hi", the queryResult I get have different `fullfilment_text` and `fulfillment_message`. Why is that? In the `fullfilment_text` it is "Hey" and in the `fulfillment_message` is says "Good day!". Which makes me confused. Has anyone encountered similar situations?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From the [Dialogflow API docs](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.agent.sessions/detectIntent#QueryResult), it appears that `fulfillmentText` is a legacy field:

> The text to be pronounced to the user or shown on the screen. **Note:** This is a legacy field, `fulfillmentMessages` should be preferred.